# Shorter way of binding too many variables in prepared statement

Tags: php, prepared-statement

I am using the prepared statement for CRUD in PHP. My code snippet :

```
$SQL="INSERT INTO Dress(DressID, Description, Size, Price, EntryDate, CategoryID, ColorID) 
            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Description=?, Size=?, Price=?, EntryDate=?, CategoryID=?, ColorID=?";
        $stmt=$connection->prepare($SQL);
        $stmt->bind_param("ssssss", $ColorID, $Color, $Color);
```

Then, I have to repeat the variables binding in `bind_param` function, like `bind_param("sssssssss", $var1, $var2, $var1, $var2, $var3..)`.
Is there any way to shorten this binding?

Comment: You could instead use an array and pass that to `PDO->execute`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the parameters to the `->execute()` method, like this:

```
$stmt->execute([123, 'red', 'green', ... ]);
```

If you keep the parameters in an array, instead of assigning them to variables, then binding them to the prepared statement can become rather trivial.